# Convert recursive matlab function to C code using mex coder

Tags: c#, c, matlab, mex

I need to convert a recursive function in matlab to C using matlab mex coder. The recursive matlab function is given below.

```
function [ cycle ] = f_cycle( adj_N, vect ,k )
cycle = [];
for i = 1: size(adj_N,1)
    l_v= size(vect,2);
    if(adj_N(vect(l_v),i)==1 )
        if(size(find(vect==i),2)==0)
            c1 = f_cycle(adj_N,[vect i],k);
        elseif(i==k && vect(l_v-1)~=k)
            c1 = [vect k];
        else
            c1 = [];
        end
        if(size(c1,1)==1 && size(c1,2) ~=0)
            c1 = [c1 zeros(1,size(adj_N,1)+1-size(c1,2))];
        end
        cycle = [cycle;c1];
    end

end
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @mch   I tried but it said "cannot convert recursive function, need extensive change to the function".  Can you suggest how I can convert it to C(mex coder or manually)..  I am not strong in C

Comment: @Maximus I suggest you have a look at this documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html . It contains a more or less bare minimum example. I once wrote a MATLAB Mex file in C and I know that it is a little bit annoying to get access to the arguments of the function you are passing in from MATLAB.

Comment: @KonradKleine   I know how to convert the usual matlab script. But here I need to convert recursive matlab function to C. Currently I am getting an error saying that you cant convert the recursive function

Comment: @Maximus then please tell more exactly what you code looks like as well as the error message you're getting.

Comment: You can 1:1 convert a recursive Matlab function to a recursive C function manually and then write a small connection in a `mexFunction` which calls the C version of the recursive function. How to get the internal Matlab to C converter doing the job I don't know.